# ForbiddenAttributesError in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting Forbidden Attributes Error even though I have used strong parameters in Rails. I have two models: Posts and Categories. 
Here is my Post Controller:
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts=Post.all
    end

```
def new
    @post=Post.new
    @category=Category.all
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path,:notice=>"Post saved"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end

def allowed_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id)
end
```

end

And here is my view for posts/new:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %></br>
        <%= f.text_field :title%><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %></br>
        <%= f.text_area :body%><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect{|x| [x.name,x.id]},{:include_blank =>"Select one"}%><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Add Post" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

But I am still getting Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `allowed_params` instead of `params[:post]`:

`@post = Post.new(allowed_params)`

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me